# Error when visiting https://www.example.com

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, webserver

My site is running on apache2 (Ubuntu 18.x)

When I visit either example.com or http://example.com or https://example.com - everything is fine.

But when I enter [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in the address bar, a request is sent to https://www.example.com (can reproduce with curl -I https://www.example.com)

Now this gives me a certificate error:

```
SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.example.com'
```

It seems the certificate only matches mysite.org and not [www.mysite.org](http://www.mysite.org).
I tried to resolve this by redirecting all traffic that's https://www. to https://

To test my configuration (made in .htaccess) I made a redirection for all https traffic
And that works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.be [R=301,L]
```

Result:

```
curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2022 08:01:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://google.be
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Yet, when requesting https://www.example.com results in the same error as above!
In essence: the certificate error is thrown before the redirection takes place (or it seems like this)

Can anyone explain to me what's going on and how to fix this? I would rather not buy another SSL certificate that includes [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and use redirection instead.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming plus you do bad obfuscation. But 1) certificates need to have the specific names involved, or wildcards (but those can't cover both apex and www at the same time, so you still need to have at least 2 names) 2) HTTP/HTTPS redirections happen AFTER TLS handshake and certificate validation, so you still need a valid certificate (with the correct name) BEFORE even thinking about redirecting anything. Your hosting provider should be able to help you on these topics.

Comment: Also certificates are free in multiple CAs, like Let's Encrypt. You can have two separate certificates (one for apex, one for www), or one combining the two names. There are advantages and inconvenients in both cases.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank your for your answer, this is clear now why the redirect doesn't fix the issue. Also how could I improve my obfuscation?. Thank you!